# Cannot append 2D array

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, nested-for-loop

I'm trying to create an eight-puzzle game solver, and I have a little problem. My states are being stored as grids(represented by 2D- lists). I am trying to keep track of every resulting state by appending to a succ_states list whenever a move is made by the computer. However, my succ_states 2D array only shows the current state and erases previous states in the list.

Here's my code snippet for the downward move:

```
def actions(self, state):
    actions = []
    succ_states = []
    print()
    rows = [row for row in state]
    for row in rows:
        for i in row:
            # D
            if i == 0 and state.index(row) != 2:
                print(row, "down action, finally!")
                print("Index of i = ", row.index(i))
                new_row = rows[state.index(row) + 1]
                zero = i
                zero_index = row.index(zero)
                row[zero_index] = new_row[zero_index]
                new_row[zero_index] = zero
                actions.append("D")
                succ_states.append(rows)
    return actions, succ_states
```

Using the initial state [[1, 3, 0], [6, 7, 8], [4, 2, 5]], actions returns [[[8, 7, 3], [5, 4, 6], [2, 1, 0]], [[8, 7, 3], [5, 4, 6], [2, 1, 0]]]. I don't get why it removes the first resulting state and appends the second state twice. I tried changing the position of the append statements and even tried to extend, but nothing is working.

Comment: I pasted your code in an interpreter and I am not getting the same result. See here (https://www.mycompiler.io/view/28vQivRVqBE). For the input you mention, action returns ['D','D']. Edit: Ichanged the URL as the other site was not saving correctly

Comment: Hi! My actions list is fine, the problem is with the succ_states. It does not include the fist successor state where 0 is on the second row.

Comment: Why do you append `rows` here? `succ_states.append(rows)`. Without further looking into it, I would guess this is a typo and you want `succ_states.append(row)` instead.

Comment: I'm trying to add the entire grid to the succ_states list. So the resulting succ_states should be a large list of lists. succ_states.append(row) will only add the row to the list, but succ_states.append(rows) adds all the rows in the resulting state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending rows, but this appends a *reference* to the list, not a copy. This means that when you later modify rows (or one of the items in row, which are lists in themselves), you modify the contents of succ_states as well.

The fix is to append a copy of rows. And, in this case that rows is a list of lists, then you need to use deepcopy.

I believe this will implement the behavior you seek:

```
import copy
def actions(self,state):
    actions = []
    succ_states = []
    print()
    rows = [row for row in state]
    for row in rows:
        for i in row:
            # D
            if i == 0 and state.index(row) != 2:
                print(row, "down action, finally!")
                print("Index of i = ", row.index(i))
                new_row = rows[state.index(row) + 1]
                zero = i
                zero_index = row.index(zero)
                row[zero_index] = new_row[zero_index]
                new_row[zero_index] = zero
                actions.append("D")
                succ_states.append(copy.deepcopy(rows))
    return actions, succ_states
```